# Dynamically calling a class only works on localhost

Tags: php, laravel

On my Laravel 8 application, I have a scenario where I generate the class name a call it. Here is the piece of code for it that I'm calling inside a trait:

```
$crm_class = "App\Lib\CRM\\" . Str::studly($lead->crm->name);

if (!class_exists($crm_class)) {
     throw new \Exception('CRM CLass Not Found: ' . $crm_class);
}

return (new $crm_class)->generateLead($lead, $request);
```

Basically, depending on the name of the lead's CRM, I call a class that deals with that particular CRM. This could for example resolve to something like App\Lib\CRM\Acme

This works perfectly in my localhost setup, but when I run it on my AWS EC2 instance, the exception is thrown that **"CRM CLass Not Found: \App\Lib\CRM\Acme"**.

I'm **not** using any `use` statements on the top for the CRM classes. I've also tried adding a `\` before `App` with no success. I'm expecting to have about 5 different unique CRM classes.

Any idea why the code works on localhost and not elsewhere?

Comment: You report the exception message as `"CRM class not found"`, this cannot be. It must at least be `"CRM class not found: "` if the variable `$crm_class` is empty. This may sound as nitpicking, but if you want us to answer your question every detail can be important, even if you think it is not. So, if the message is really as you report the code in your question is not responsible for it.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I modified the exception message I'm receiving to show the full message.

Comment: Check the case of names on all your files and directories. Mac/Windows are not case-sensitive (by default) but Linux is. This can cause problems with autoloading.

Comment: Thanks for adding the whole message. I checked `class_exists()` and it does call your `__autoload` by default, so that's not it. I did notice that `$crm_class = "App\Lib\CRM\\"` doesn't have a backslash at the beginning, however in the error message it reports `\App\Lib\CRM\Acme`. Can you explain that? Perhaps you now have that backslash in your code, but you didn't have it in the question? In the end I think we won't be able to get to the bottom of this, given the information in your question. There's nothing magical about this, you just have to try some simple debugging steps.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that `Str::studly` was producing a capital L in the class name, but my class name was using a lower case l. I changed the case, and the issue is resolved.

Comment: `I added the exact message` + `was producing a capital L in the class name` so it was not the exact error message, there is no L in Acme … glad you found the issue though